# How do display json data in view using Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, coffeescript

I am learning Angularjs and trying to implement it in my C# web MVC application for the first time.

I am unable to get json format data returned from my controller to display in my view which uses Angular/Razor for data purposes

In my C# controller I return json data to my coffe scrip/js

```
public ActionResult Load (string id){
//data retrieved from model and formatted in json here
return Json(jsonData ,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In My coffee script I have:

```
define ['test'], (app) ->
     ($scope, $http, $location) ->
        $scope.vData = (id) ->
            $.ajax
                url: 'Mobile/Load?id=1237'
            .done (response) -> 
                alert response
                $scope.vdata = [response]
                $scope.$apply() unless $scope.$$phase
```

When I launch the application the view has  an alert button that I used to test If I can see the data from the json response:

The alert shows data in the following format:

```
{
   "versions":{
      "is_live":"true",
      "type":"multiple",
      "rendition":{
         "@name":"My Test",
         "@url":"http://test.net/location/test.m3u8",
         "@thumbnail":"http:// test.net/location/testimg/cam.png",
         "@thumbnail_update_interval":"10"
      }
   }
}
```

In my view I have tried to get data in a  label several ways but unsuccessful:

```
<label>{{vdata.is_live}}</label>
<label>{{vdata.versions.is_live}}</label>
<label>{{is_live}}</label>
```

While debugging in my browser I noticed that  json data is in a string format and not an object.

Could this be the problem?

Can someone please help me to display data in my view from the json data using Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll change two things. The first one if the json data is in a string format you should parse it using JSON.parse(jsondata) when you receive the data on the client.

I don't know coffee script but i'll add what is missing using javascript just to show you what i'll change :

```
define ['test'], (app) ->
     ($scope, $http, $location) ->
        $scope.vData = (id) ->
            $.ajax
                url: 'Mobile/Load?id=1237'
            .done (response) -> 
                alert response
                $scope.vdata = JSON.parse( [response] )
                $scope.$apply() unless $scope.$$phase
```

and then try:

```
<label>{{vdata.versions.is_live}}</label>
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I have tried that before. I changed the question to show that I have tried that